# Corda contracts & non-deterministic contract rules

Tags: corda

Contract commands in Corda need to be verified in a deterministic way. Why then is it possible to verify the following expressions?

`LocalDateTime.MAX >= LocalDateTime.now() // true - LocalDateTime.MAX is a long time away!`

`UUID.randomUUID().toString().contains("4") // true - all v4 UUIDs contain a "4"`

I would have expected something to go wrong with the contract command, since `LocalDateTime.now()` and `UUID.randomUUID()` are do not produce deterministic results.

Why is it possible to verify these expressions from within a contract command, given they do not produce deterministic values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think Corda has the DJVM ready yet. So you can write that sort of code, but you shouldn't since it isn't deterministic. At the moment it is more of a guideline of "write deterministic code" rather than a rule when the code will throw errors if it is not.

Comment: That's correct. As of 3.x, the node doesn't use the DJVM yet.

Comment: @Joel when Corda _does_ use the DJVM, will this restrict non-deterministic APIs across the whole CorDapp, or only when used within a contract command?

Comment: Only within `verify`.